# Null check with logical operator 'and' throws error while '&&' doesn't in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, if-statement, logical-operators, nullable, kotlin-null-safety

The difference between `&&` and `and` and the difference between `||` and `or`:

- `&&` and `||` use short-circuit evaluation while
- `and` and `or` always evaluate every condition

[Kotlin doc for "and"](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-boolean/and.html)

But apart from that, I get different behaviour for the following example:

Using `&&`, this snippet perfectly works:

```
var str1: String? = "Good Morning"
var str2: String? = "How's it going"

if (str1 != null && str2 != null) {
    println(str1.length + str2.length)
}
```

When I replace the `&&` with `and` I have to add parenthesis around both conditions, otherwise the compiler seems to get confused because I get the error: `Operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'String?' and 'BigInteger'`

Using `and` and adding parenthesis:

```
var str1: String? = "Good Morning"
var str2: String? = "How's it going"

if ((str1 != null) and (str2 != null)) {
    println(str1.length + str2.length)
}
```

But this last snippet throws:

```
Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String?
```

Shouldn't both expressions do precisely the same? Evaluate both conditions and only execute the `println` when both `String` values are `non-null`? What is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&&` is different from `and` in an additional way in that it introduces a smart cast from `String?` to `String`, allowing you to access `length` by saying `str1.length` and `str2.length`, rather than using `str1?.length` and `str2?.length`.

From the [Kotlin language specification](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-inference.html#smart-cast-types):

> Smart casts are introduced by the following Kotlin constructions.
>
> - Conditional expressions (`if`)
> - When expressions (`when`);
> - Elvis operator (operator `?:`);
> - Safe navigation operator (operator `?.`);
> - Logical conjunction expressions (operator `&&`);
> - Logical disjunction expressions (operator `||`);
> - Not-null assertion expressions (operator `!!`);
> - Cast expressions (operator `as`);
> - Type-checking expressions (operator `is`);
> - Simple assignments;
> - Platform-specific cases: different platforms may add other kinds of expressions which introduce additional smart cast sources.

You need the extra parenthesis because [`and`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-boolean/and.html), being an infix function, has a higher precedence than `&&`, which is not an infix function. See all the precedences [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#expressions).